# ¿Cómo configurar el archivo .env de Lumen para el acceso a base de datos en Docker?

Tags: docker, lumen

Entiendo que Docker (estoy usando la versión de desarrollo) tiene un DNS interno que maneja las peticiones de contenedores que están en la misma red. En este caso, yo estoy usando la red `bridge`. La idea es que en vez de usar las IP internas, se puedan usar los nombres de los contenedores, ya que la asignación de IPs es dinámica.

Pues bien, la parte de mi archivo `.env` que interesa para este problema se ve así:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.2
DB_PORT=3306
```

Ya que el contenedor de `MariaDB` tiene esa dirección IP, Lumen puede comunicarse correctamente y usar la información de la base de datos.

Siguiendo la lógica, pensé que podía sustituir la dirección IP por el nombre del contenedor. El archivo `.env` se vería así:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=dmladb
DB_PORT=3306
```

Docker debería poder resolver `dmladb` como el nombre de uno de los contenedores y saber la dirección IP asociada, pero no lo hace. En `Lumen` obtengo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

¿Existe alguna otra configuración que deba hacer en Lumen o en Docker para que el DNS interno funcione bien?

Comment: Estás usando docker para desarrollo o producción? Agrega la configuración de docker a la pregunta.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Ya lo hice. Gracias por la observación.